# Why can't I open another emacsclient after activating follow-mode?

Tags: emacs, development-environment, daemon

I use Emacs for many things (the list seems to be growing every day). I like to have several frames open (so I can keep them in separate workspaces), so I first start it with `emacs --daemon` and then connect various clients to it with `emacsclient -t`.

One thing I have recently added to that list is writing papers. I write in Markdown, which allows easy version tracking with Git. In order to make it more readable, I usually split the frame into 3 or 4 windows vertically, and use `follow-mode` to split the paper between them.

I recently ran into a problem with this setup. Emacs would randomly stop accepting connections, and any time I ran `emacsclient -t` it would hang, never opening the frame. It took me a while to figure out why it happened, but I finally did. To reproduce:

1. Start emacs with `emacs --daemon`
2. Connect the first client with `emacsclient -t <file>` where `<file>` is some plaintext file.
3. Activate follow-mode with `M-x follow-mode`
4. Attempt to connect another client with `emacsclient -t`. This client will hang and never connect.

Deactivating follow-mode after that point had no effect, clients were still unable to connect. If I never activate follow-mode, I never have a problem.

I also tried it without loading any init files (`emacs --daemon --no-init-file --no-site-file`), with the same result.

I'm running `GNU Emacs 23.4.1`, from the Ubuntu software repositories.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Looks like a bug in follow-mode.  I cannot reproduce it with with emacs 24.3.  You may want to try to upgrade emacs or (if that is not an option) just upgrade follow-mode.

Comment: @juanleon Thanks for the help. I upgraded to `Emacs 24` and no longer have this problem. If you'd like to post that info as an answer I will accept it as such. If I narrow down what causes the problem I will post back here (and file a bug report).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a bug in follow-mode (I cannot reproduce it with with emacs 24.3).  Upgrading emacs would be a solution for fixing the problem.

[This](http://emacs.1067599.n5.nabble.com/bug-3926-23-1-50-Follow-mode-makes-Emacs-server-unavailable-td36281.html) seem to be the official thread for this problem, which provides some adittional information and a workaround for those unable or unwilling to upgrade emacs.